# how to create a custom field and save in custom tab in order view magento 2

Tags: custom-field, sales-order-view, customtab

I want to create a custom field in the custom tab in order view the below comments and save the value and also add in user role permission only admin see and add the value here Magento 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

check the below link...
I thick it will be helpful for you.

[Click the
link](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-custom-tab-in-admin-sales-order-view-magento-2/)

Comment: but i need a custom field and save the value of a field in the tab not order id and last history